# Magical record save memory only

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have code like this:

```
Person *person = [Person MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"FirstName"
                                   withValue:@"Forrest"];
NSLog("Person:%@",person);// age = 20
person.age = 25;
NSLog("Person:%@",[Person MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"FirstName"
                                   withValue:@"Forrest"]);// age = 25
```

I saw that when I set `persion = 25` MagicalRecord also save it to store. Sometime I just want to save only `person` not save to`PersistentStore`. How can I do it?thanks

Comment: have you tried making a copy of the object ?

Comment: thank. but how? sorry I'm new on Core data.

Comment: as long as your persistent store is not an in-memory store you will have all created objects persist on disk. You could delete objects that you want not stored after finish using them

Answer (score 1):

Setting `person.age` doesn't save the new value into persistent store. The value is saved only when you save the `NSManagedObjectContext` in which `person` object exists (you probably do that using one of the Magical Record `save` methods).  You can discard changes made in `person` object before you save the context, so they won't be saved into the persistent store:

`[person.managedObjectContext refreshObject:person mergeChanges:NO]`